# How is it possible to use forEach method in this case?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have this code

```
router.get('/get-data',function(req,res,next){
    var resultArray = [];
    mongo.connect(url,function(err,db){

        assert.equal(null,err); 
        var dbTest = db.db('test');
        var cursor = dbTest.collection('user-data').find();
        cursor.forEach(function(doc,err){
            assert.equal(null,err);
            resultArray.push(doc);
        },function(){
            db.close();
            res.render('index',{items: resultArray});
        });
    });
});
```

I checked the **cursor** variable with `Array.isArray()` to see if it s an Array and it returned false. I thought that forEach method applies to arrays. How is possible to be used for something that is not an array?

Comment: Arrays are not the only types with a forEach method

Answer (score 2):

Cursors have their own `forEach` method. Try logging your cursor to console, you'll see it's methods.

[cursor.forEach(function)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/#cursor.forEach)